# Angular 2 @Component Styles

Tags: css, typescript, angular

How can I use Angular 2 styles in @Component with multiple classes on the same tag?

```
@Component({
    styles: `.class1 .class2{background-color:red;}`
})
```

This generates the following css code:

```
.class1[<RANDOM_ANGULAR_ATTR>] .class2[<RANDOM_ANGULAR_ATTR>]{
    background-color: red; 
}
```

This will not select a tag defined like this:

```
<div class=".class1 .class2" RANDOM_ANGULAR_ATTR></div>
```

Is there any way to make this approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styles should have the classes without a space between them. Multiple classes in the same selector must be written directly after each another – with no white space. For example:

```
.class1.class2 { background-color:red; }
```

And in order to select your object you should have the classes added like this:

```
<div class="class1 class2">Test css</div>
```

See the code below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [
`
.class1.class2{background-color:red};
` ],
  template: `
<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
<div class="class1 class2">Test css</div>
`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

For more options see also the following blog posts (about Shadow DOM, Encapsulation Types .. any other cool things):

1. https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components
2. http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Removing the whitespace indeed did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Justin Schwartzenberger's NG-Conf talk on CSS styles and the randomly generated tag? https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLOETEcp3DkCq788xapkP_OU-78jhTf68j&v=J5Bvy4KhIs0

potential options are to:

1. Use a styleUrls template
2. change encapsulation
3. use a different class (since its only relevant to this component its ok to name something simple vs using 2)